# Read from SQL into visual studios DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I am having a problem, I am trying to read from a Sql Database, its called Testing and contains a table called TimeDate, inside of it, it has the property called DoB(Date of Birth) with a value of Date(not DateTime). Inside visual studios, i read from the database and it returns the Date into a variable list called DoB with the data type of DateTime(as far as i know there is no "Date" only data type). But when i display the information all i want to see is the month, the day, and the year (3/27/1990) but what i actually see is this 3/27/1990 12:00:00 AM... I dont want that time part to be displayed, even if i use the .Date property, it still displays the time part, is there anyway of getting rid of this?

This is the code i use to Read/Write to the database and display the information in the console

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the birthday you would like to input?(YYYY-MM-DD)");
        DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.ReadLine());
        NewDate(newDate);

        List<DateTime> dates = Read("FindDates", new SqlParameter[] { });
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        foreach (DateTime date in dates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static string connectionString = @"Server = ONSHORE-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database = Testing;Trusted_Connection = True;";

    public static void NewDate(DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] {
            new SqlParameter("@TimeDate", date.Date)
        };
            Write("InputDate", parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Writing to Database");   
        }
    }
    public static int Write(string statement, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement, con))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                return Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
    private static List<DateTime> Read(string statement, SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement, con))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader data = command.ExecuteReader();
                List<DateTime> Dates = new List<DateTime>();
                while (data.Read())
                {
                    DateTime date = new DateTime();
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(data["DoB"]);
                    Dates.Add(date);
                }
                return Dates;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") on the VS variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already a `DateTime`, you just need to format it's string representation like;

```
yourDateTime.ToString("M'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```

or

```
yourDateTime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I strongly suspect you use just your `DateTime`'s as `yourDateTime` and probably in representation part, this will call [`DateTime.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ToString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this uses [`"G"` standard date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) by default.

And this specifier returns [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) and .[`LongTimePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) combination with seperated a white space of your `CurrentCulture`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to display by dd/MM/yyyy

```
    var dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```